# Partial Sum of numeric vector by row from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I'm working on a database with repeated measures, and I need to calculate the sum of a numeric vector by category and remove repetitions.

`Category  Area`
`A         30`
`A         15`
`A         20`
`B         45`
`B         30`
`C         12`
`D         18`
`D         22`

And transform to:

`Category  Area`
`A         65`
`B         75`
`C         12`
`D         40`

How can i get this in R?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a data.frame called df with columns Category and Area

```
df2 <- aggregate.data.frame(x = df["Area"], by = df["Category"], FUN = sum)
```